# how to check database limit and input no of count?

Tags: sql-server-2008, laravel-4

I have 10 images. im inserted that 10 images into database.then im tring to insert one more image.i want to one error message "only 10 images are occur" how to check database limit and input no of count?using laravel can you give validation code using laravel
 my write controller.php is here

```
if(ForumGallery::count>=5)
          {return "only 5 images";}
          else
          { return Redirect::route('addgallery');}
```

but an error occur
http://Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Undefined class constant 'count'

```
my validation part
$validate=Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
       'galname'=>'required|max:20',
       'galimg'=>'required|max:200kb|Mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png
                     ,pneg',

      ));
```

Comment: I don't know about `laravel` but normal way would be check the count and then if `count>=10` then show error message. And no one is going to write your code for you try something and then come here .

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel eloquent, to return count use:

```
$max_image = 5;
if(ForumGallery::all()->count() <= $max_image)
{
  ForumGallery::create($input); //call the function to upload image here
  return Redirect::route('addgallery'); 
}
else
{
  return "max image upload reached!";
}
```

Comment: iam adding this code if(ForumGallery::all()->count() >= 5)  is here if(ForumGallery::all()->count()>= 3)
              {
            return "only 3 images";
              }
              else
              {
                return Redirect::route('addgallery');
              }frist 2 images are inserted properly.but 3rd image inserted got an error message "only 3 images..also that image save into database.. then howmany images are inserted..all contain same error message and save into database.

Comment: iam only 3 images are save into database then how many images are inserted i want to only error meassage not want to save image into database

Comment: I don't really understand what you want exactly here, the solution I gave above is to solve the error that you get in your original question, and it'll return the message when the count() hits a certain no, which for the eg. is higher or equal to 5, it's not going to insert anything into the DB, or do you mean you want to insert the data when the count() is under 5 and give error when it hits above 5?.

Comment: sorry.........i want to insert the data into database(only 5 data) when the count()=5 then insert 6th(next data) i want  error message only. but using this code the 5 data's are correctly inserted.then insert 6th(next data) i got an error msg and also insert into database..pls help...

Comment: I think it'll be easier to understand if you edit your question with a complete code of your function, else it's hard for me to get your logic from your current explanation.

Comment: my controller.php code is here $file=Input::file('galimg');
        $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
      //->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move('uploads',$filename);
        ForumGallery::create([
         'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
         'galimg'=>$filename
        ]);
              if(ForumGallery::all()->count()>3)
              {
            return "only 3 images";
              }
              else
              {
                return Redirect::route('addgallery');
              }
        }
              return Redirect::route('gallery');

Comment: using this code how much of images are insert into database successfully...but i want only 5 images are insert into database. then im tring to insert next image into database ,i want error msg(only 5 images). but this code if(ForumGallery::all()->count()>3)
              {
            return "only 3 images";
              }
              else
              {
                return Redirect::route('addgallery');
              }   insert 5 images successfully,after insert next image i got an error msg and also that image go to database. i want only error msg no want go to database...

Comment: I've edited the solutions based on my brief understanding of your logic, basically it'll upload the image if the count() is under the $limit and return error otherwise without uploading the image.

Comment: srry........ i have an error in this line.... uploadImage($input);
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Call to undefined function uploadImage() i cnt understand what u mean it..
call the function to upload image here???

Comment: my controller.hp is here.....public function getgallery()
$file=Input::file('galimg');
        $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
      //->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move('uploads',$filename);
        ForumGallery::create([
         'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
         'galimg'=>$filename
        ]);

Comment: $max_image = 3;
               if(ForumGallery::all()->count() < $max_image)
                  {
                     uploadImage($file); //call the function to upload image here
                     return Redirect::route('addgallery'); 
                  }
                   else
                     {
                      return "max image upload reached!";
                      }
        }
              return Redirect::route('gallery');
    }

Comment: i got new error using this code ... $max_image = 5;
if(ForumGallery::all()->count() <= $max_image)
{
  ForumGallery::create($file); //call the function to upload image here
  return Redirect::route('addgallery'); 
}
else
{
  return "max image upload reached!";
} error is 
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\wys\wys\app\controllers\AddgalleryController.php on line 33 and defined

Comment: well if that's solve your question you should label the solution as the answer, so the thread can be considered solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Controller.php page
  public function getgallery()
  {
    $validate=Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
    'galname'=>'required|max:20',
     'galimg'=>'required|max:200kb|Mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png
                     ,pneg',
   ));
    if($validate->fails())
     {
        return Redirect::route('getgallery')
        ->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
     }
    else
    {
     $file=Input::file('galimg');
        $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
      //->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //$file->move('uploads',$filename);
        // ForumGallery::create([
           //  'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
           //  'galimg'=>$filename
           // ]);
          $max_image = 2;
           if(ForumGallery::all()->count() < $max_image)
              {
               $file->move('uploads',$filename);
               ForumGallery::create([
            'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
            'galimg'=>$filename
           ]);//call the function to upload image here
                 return Redirect::route('addgallery'); 
              }
               else
                 {
                  return "max image upload reached!";
                  }
    }
          return Redirect::route('gallery');
    }
```